# Azure AD B2C - Profile editing policy can no longer be customized

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

It seems we are no longer able to customize the UI of the built-in profile editing policy (picture below).
[image]

Maybe I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must select at least 1 attribute before you can set the custom page UI.